# trying to install gmp on 32bit ubuntu and getting exec binary format error after trying to install gcc & mpfr

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, gmp

I'm trying to install gcc-4.9.2 on a 32-bit Ubuntu and in config.log it says:
Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+
So I downloaded mpfr-3.1.2, and the INSTALL file says I need GMP 4.1 or later.
then I downloaded gmp-6.0.0 and ran the ./configure - the config.log says in several places:
./a.out cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.
I noticed both a -m64 switch and a -mx32 switch

```
configure:5625: checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 
Test compile: 
 configure:5639: gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64  conftest.c >&5
configure:5642: $? = 0
configure:5647: ./a.out || ./b.out || ./a.exe || ./a_out.exe || ./conftest
./configure: line 5648: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

...

failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6665: result: no, program does not run
configure:5546: cc -c conftest.c >&5
configure:5549: $? = 0
configure:5552: checking whether cc is gcc
configure:5554: result: yes
configure:5568: cc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
configure:5571: $? = 1
configure:5625: checking compiler cc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 
Test compile: 
configure:5639: cc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64  conftest.c >&5
configure:5642: $? = 0
configure:5647: ./a.out || ./b.out || ./a.exe || ./a_out.exe || ./conftest
./configure: line 5648: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
./configure: line 5648: ./b.out: No such file or directory
./configure: line 5648: ./a.exe: No such file or directory
./configure: line 5648: ./a_out.exe: No such file or directory
./configure: line 5648: ./conftest: No such file or directory
configure:5650: $? = 127
failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6665: result: no, program does not run
configure:5568: gcc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
configure:5571: $? = 1
configure:5625: checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mx32
```

I'm wondering if I need to tell the ./configure script that I have a 32-bit machine.

Comment: I'm also seeing "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: at the end it says: "checking for suitable m4... configure error: No usable m4 in $PATH or /usr/5bin (see config.log for reasons)

Comment: I just installed m4 and ran the ./configure again and it shows a summary of build options: Version, Host type, ABI and I see a libtool and some directories so I think it worked.

Comment: Try `aptitude build-dep gcc`

Comment: Why are you not using Ubuntu's package manager to install software? As for GMP, you could go read its doc on gmplib.org, it talks about a variable called ABI. It is normal for a configure script to "fail" many tests. Did the installation actually fail? You are not saying.

Comment: If you're really going to build a toolchain, you should probably read through [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/). Pay particular attention to chapter *5. Constructing a Temporary System*.

Comment: I found libgmp.a in the gmp-xxx/.libs directory, copied it to the mpfr-xxx/ directory and ran ./configure --with-gmp-include=. --with-gmp-lib=. and it worked. Or at least now I have a Makefile. Elliot, I'm trying to make a cross-compiler for the ARM Cirrus EP9302 on the TS-72XX. I've already tried Crosstool-NG, buildroot and another one before that with little success. The Linux from Scratch seems to explain a lot the others assume you already know. Thanks.

Comment: With mine, I went sudo apt-get install build-dep gcc. I still have to install GMP, MPFR and MPC, but thanks anyway.

Comment: the make for mpfr quits with ld: cannot find -lgmp and something about libmpfr.la - I checked the installed pkgs and I have libmpfr4. @MarcGlisse - I checked the gmp config.log and it says abi=32.